# Remove Character Match that Occurs at the End of String

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove a string match that occurs only at the end of a series of string in each element of a character vector.  The string match is "UR".  I've tried stringr but its too broad to use `str_replace(emply3,"UR","")` since it grabs all "UR" matches.  Help is appreciated!

emply3

```
("FORT608UR", "FRES406UR", "FTSUR", "GADS401UR", "GAIN512UR", 
"GAIN513UR", "GLEN036UR", "GOLD137UR", "GRAN238UR", "GRAN308UR", 
"GRAN326UR", "GREA530UR", "GREE508UR", "GREE555UR", "GREE637UR", 
"GREE737UR", "GREE845UR", "GULF028UR", "HAGE124UR", "HANF206UR", 
"HARR442UR", "HARR551UR", "HATT628UR", "HICK837UR", "HINE913UR", 
"HOLL126UR", "HONO115UR", "HOUM322UR", "HOUS448UR", "HSPUR", 
"HUNT554UR", "HUNT601UR", "IDAH816UR", "INDI918UR", "IOWA919UR", 
"ITHA036UR", "JACK126UR", "JACK128UR", "JACK212UR", "JACK337UR", 
"JACUR", "JANE555UR", "JEFUR", "JOHN742UR", "JOHN747UR", "JOPL929UR", 
"JORUR", "KALA026UR", "KANK117UR", "KANS129UR", "KENN453UR", 
"KILL648UR", "KING736UR", "KING747UR", "KNOX947UR", "KOKO018UR")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `$` to signal the end of the text:

```
gsub("UR$", "", emply3)
```

If you want to use `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace(regex = "UR$", replacement = "", str = a)
```